# rankntypes: Illegal polymorphic or qualified type

Tags: haskell, higher-rank-types

I am trying to expand (or trying to find out whether it's possible to expand) a function with a type signature that already goes to the limits of my knowledge, because of the libraries I'm using which expose quite polymorphic types and APIs, to something even more polymorphic.

I'm using `persistent` and `hsqml`, both libraries having pretty hairy types at moments, at least for me.

I need to wrap `persistent` entities to `hsqml` "proxy" objects to be exposed to `QML` (javascript basically).
For that purpose I made myself a helper, called `getStandardClassMembers`. You use it like so:

```
instance DefaultClass (Entity Project) where
    classMembers = getStandardClassMembers
        [
            ("name", projectName),
            ("hasCustomIcon", text . not . BS.null . projectIcon),
            ("hasDev", projectHasDev), -- TODO bool as string, ugly..
            ("hasUat", projectHasUat),
            ("hasStaging", projectHasStage),
            ("hasProd", projectHasProd)
        ]
        []
```

The definition of `getStandardClassMembers` is [there](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/projectpad/blob/e82a359b7cb8b96c400f70f8d45b59ebef4f46e0/src/Model.hs#L114-L125). That define a javascript object with the members I specify, and calls the haskell functions I give to implement the members of the JS object.

That's pretty nice but there is a 'but'. The function in the second position in the pair must return `Text`. Here you see, for all but the first function, I should rather return a `Bool`. So ideally I would make the type signature of `getStandardClassMembers` take a type more polymorphic to not require that that second function returns necessarily a `Text`. And again I simply don't know if it's possible, but I decided to give it a shot.

So I add `RankNTypes` to the already massive list of language extensions for that file (I'm kind of forced into that due to the libraries I chose, which are otherwise wonderful).

And I change:

```
getStandardClassMembers :: (Marshal tr, ToBackendKey SqlBackend record, Typeable record,
     MarshalMode tr ICanReturnTo () ~ Yes) =>
    [(String, record -> tr)] -> [(String, ObjRef (Entity record) -> Maybe Int)]
    -> [Member (GetObjType (ObjRef (Entity record)))]
```

To:

```
getStandardClassMembers :: (Marshal tr, ToBackendKey SqlBackend record, Typeable record,
     MarshalMode tr ICanReturnTo () ~ Yes) =>
    [(String, forall tr. record -> tr)] -> [(String, ObjRef (Entity record) -> Maybe Int)]
    -> [Member (GetObjType (ObjRef (Entity record)))]
```

(so I added `forall tr.`)
and I get:

```
Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: forall tr. record -> tr
Perhaps you intended to use ImpredicativeTypes
```

Now I know just enough about these things to know that enabling `ImpredicativeTypes` is not a good idea. Plus if I enable it, it doesn't work either.

Is what I want achievable or should I give it a rest and be thankful anything works at all with those already pretty messy type signatures and language extension collections?

**EDIT** probably the right fix is to forget about my helper and go back to the basics using the `hsqml` basic API. But otherwise I'm still curious whether that would be possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic problem is that you are trying to put values of different types in one list.  Even `ImpredicativeTypes` doesn't really allow you to do that in the way that you would need.  Existential types could work with a wrapper, but I think they're overkill as well.

Instead, I suggest changing from inserting tuples to inserting something that always is the same type, based on how you were actually going to *use* the tuples.  Looking at your linked code I see

```
\(name, f) -> defPropertyConst name (return . f . entityVal . fromObjRef)
```

as the function you use on your tuples to get what you *actually* need from them.  So why not define a global function for that?

```
stdMember name f = defPropertyConst name (return . f . entityVal . fromObjRef)
```

(The name is just a suggestion; you might want something shorter or even an operator.)

Then change `getStandardClassMembers` to take a list of such values as its first argument, and probably something similar for the second.

Assuming there are no more type subtleties, you should then be able to write

```
instance DefaultClass (Entity Project) where
    classMembers = getStandardClassMembers
        [
            stdMember "name" projectName,
            stdMember "hasCustomIcon" $ text . not . BS.null . projectIcon,
            stdMember "hasDev" projectHasDev, -- TODO bool as string, ugly..
            stdMember "hasUat" projectHasUat,
            stdMember "hasStaging" projectHasStage,
            stdMember "hasProd" projectHasProd
        ]
        []
```

Comment: thanks for the tip how to reformat the code, I'll review it (together with the "back to the basics" approach that I mentioned). However what I don't fully get is, are the types in the list really different? The `forall` is exactly an attempt to uniformize the types. All like `forall a. record -> a` or something of that shape. Maybe using `forall` on a return type is more problematic? I still don't get why the `RankNTypes` approach doesn't cut it.

Comment: ah I see it now. It's what you said "Existential types could work with a wrapper". That's just it. So it's not doable, except with a wrapper, as in https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections#Existential_types -- I knew that but somehow it didn't "connect". Ok so I'll check your solution tonight and what I had in mind but I see now that just adding `forall` can't cut it. I guess the reason why lies in research papers so that's it I guess.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery I'm not sure doing existential types without wrappers is "really impossible" as much as "not worth the bother to implement when a wrapper makes it much simpler". On [https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type) there's a link to [a Haskell dialect](http://www.cs.uu.nl/groups/ST/Projects/ehc/ehc-book.pdf) that tries to do it differently.